# DbDataReader can't read Excel file created by Sql Server Reporting Services vb.net

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008

please help me.

In ASP.Net (VB), get exception when DbDataReader read each column in 'While loop'. DbDataReader can read normal Excel file, but not in Excel file created by SQL Server Reporting Services.

```
Using reader As DbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
       If Not reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("User ID")) Then
             ........
             ........
```

How can I try to work?

Comment: What does the exception message say?

Comment: i mean to read data from Excel file created in Excel application is ok. but reading data from Excel file created by SQL Server Reporting Services gets exception